# grepping string from long text

Tags: bash, shell, grep

The command below in OSX checks whether an account is disabled (or not).

I'd like to grep the string "isDisabled=X" to create a report of disabled users, but am not sure how to do this since the output is on three lines, and I'm interested in the first 12 characters of line three:

```
bash-3.2# pwpolicy -u jdoe -getpolicy
Getting policy for jdoe /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1

isDisabled=0 isAdminUser=1 newPasswordRequired=0 usingHistory=0 canModifyPasswordforSelf=1 usingExpirationDate=0 usingHardExpirationDate=0 requiresAlpha=0 requiresNumeric=0 expirationDateGMT=12/31/69 hardExpireDateGMT=12/31/69 maxMinutesUntilChangePassword=0 maxMinutesUntilDisabled=0 maxMinutesOfNonUse=0 maxFailedLoginAttempts=0 minChars=0 maxChars=0 passwordCannotBeName=0 validAfter=01/01/70 requiresMixedCase=0 requiresSymbol=0 notGuessablePattern=0 isSessionKeyAgent=0 isComputerAccount=0 adminClass=0 adminNoChangePasswords=0 adminNoSetPolicies=0 adminNoCreate=0 adminNoDelete=0 adminNoClearState=0 adminNoPromoteAdmins=0
```

Your ideas/suggestions are most appreciated! Ultimately this will be part of a Bash script. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you would use `grep` to match "`isDisabled=X`":

```
grep -o "isDisabled=."
```

---

**Explanation:**

- `grep`: invoke the grep command
- `-o`: Use the `--only-matching` option for `grep` (From grep manual: "Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line."
- `"isDisabled=."`: This is the search pattern you give to grep. The `.` is part of the regular expression, it means "match any character except for newline".

---

**Usage:**

This is how you would use it as part of your script:

```
pwpolicy -u jdoe -getpolicy | grep -oE "isDisabled=."
```

This is how you can save the result to a variable:

```
status=$(pwpolicy -u jdoe -getpolicy | grep -oE "isDisabled=.")
```

If your command was run some time prior, and the results from the command was saved to a file called "results.txt", you use it as input to `grep` as follows:

```
grep -o "isDisabled=." results.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed as

```
cat results.txt | sed -n 's/.*isDisabled=\(.\).*/\1/p'
```

This will print the value of `isDisbaled`.

Comment: Useless use of cat spotted!

Comment: I know it's not the very correct way, but that's how i use it many times.. just need to add the redirect to new file...

Comment: Use `sed -n 's/.*isDisabled=\(.\).*/\1/p' results.txt` instead.